# How to write an XML file to config a layer (GeoToolsLayer) fetched from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I need to connect to GeoServer, fetch the layer and display it in Geomajas. I have followed the instruction in this link http://www.geomajas.org/node/280 but it doesn't work for me.

The map is just blank. I don't find any compilation error or runtime exceptions in Jetty console, and there is also nothing in geoserver.log on the server. Therefore, I have no clue to figure out what the exact problem is.

For other kinds of layer (from shapefile, Google Map...), it works OK.

1. Where can I find a working XML file to config such layer?
2. How can I debug or find out the reason why the map is just blank?

Comment: Is this for a WMS or a WFS request?
Can you show the configuration file you used?

Comment: I have this problem too, but when my app begins to run on the browser, I get a warning message: `An error occurred on the server:
Unexpected problem., root cause org/geotools/filter/visitor/FixBBOXFilterVisitor"` After I close this warning dialog, nothing is showing on my map. I am using the geotools layer which is trying to fetch a vector layer from Geoserver.
Can any body help me, I didn't find any other geotools vector layer sample.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

i have configed my app using articles on http://www.geomajas.org/node/280 and http://files.geomajas.org/maven/trunk/geomajas/geomajas-layer-geotools-documentation/html/master.html#geotools links.

Comment: First link is now dead though the root organization still exists. It is for this reason link only answers are generally discouraged. Answers should at least contain a summary of the information present at the link.